How can I delay exiting Emacs?
I have this code which works to exit Emacs after seven seconds, unless "q" is pressed. Can it also work pressing "ESC"? I can't seem to get that working
(defun my-exit-emacs-with-delay ()
  "Exit Emacs after a 7-second delay, unless 'q' is pressed to abort."
  (interactive)
  (let ((timer (run-with-timer 7 nil 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
    (message "Emacs will exit in 7 seconds. Press 'q' to abort.")
    (let ((char (read-event)))
      (when (eq char ?q)
        (cancel-timer timer)
        (message "Exiting Emacs aborted.")))))

(define-key my-mode-map (kbd "C-M-q") 'my-exit-emacs-with-delay)


Why don't you try calling read-event from your *scratch* buffer and see what it returns when you type ESC? Hint: it does not return a character, it returns a symbol. Can you see what you have to do to your function to accommodate that?

Not sure if the O.P. is interested in read-char or read-char-exclusive, but they both have built-in optional timers to wait for user input.  I have a count-down timer to start Emacs with no user configuration by pressing the letter "q", or load the full monty when no user input ... there is a thread where a forum participant wrote the function that counts down visually ...

Please check one or more of the solutions above, ask if you have any questions, and provide an answer based on them (or not: if you find a better solution, use it). But don't leave questions orphaned like this.
